# Test for changes in proportion through times?

Tags: time-series, probability, hypothesis-testing, proportion

I want to test for a change in proportions through time, and see that there are a number of unanswered questions related to this.

I have a dataset of counts that belong in one of three mutually-exclusive categories ("small", "medium", and "large"). I want to know if the percentages change through time, but just not sure how to set it up. I think that it could be a glm with a poisson, but just not sure. Here is some code that generates two datasets, one with proportions staying the same and one with proportions changing.

```r
    years = seq(1, 20)
    a = seq(30, 30+length(years)-1)
    func = function(x) rpois(1, x)
    small = lapply(a, FUN = func)
    small = unlist(small)
    
    med = unlist(lapply(a*.2, FUN = func))
    large = unlist(lapply(a*.1, FUN = func))
    
    category = c(rep("small", length(years)), rep("medium", 
                 length(years)), rep("large", length(years)))
    count = c(small, med, large)
    df = data.frame(rep(years,3), category, count)
    names(df) = c("years", "category", "count")
    
    plot(df$years,df$count,col=as.factor(df$category))
        
    # now change proportions through time
    medProp = seq(.2,.5,length.out=20)
    largeProp = seq(.1,.001,length.out=20)
    
    med2 = unlist(lapply(a* medProp,FUN = func))
    large2 = unlist(lapply(a* largeProp,FUN = func))
    
    count2 = c(small,med2,large2)
    df2 = data.frame(rep(years,3),category,count2)
    names(df2) = c("years","category","count")
    
    plot(df2$years,df2$count,col=as.factor(df2$category))
```